# ColdFusion: How to use SharePoint's getListItems()

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, coldfusion, moss

Does anybody know how I could get all items from a SharePoint-List?

It should be possible to call the function [getListItems()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774532.aspx) with 4 parameters:

- One for the list where the information is stored in,
- the second for the query,
- the third for the displayed fields, and
- the fourth that specifies the number of rows to return.

My code is:

```
<cfobject webservice="http://sharepointserver:16999/blog/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx?wsdl" name="siteDataService"
    password="pw"
    username="user"
    >

<cfset siteDataService.GetListItems(
    "{9BE74555-1150-4AC8-ADE7-EE52923D7CE8}", 
    "<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name=""ID"" /><Value Type=""Counter"">3</Value></Lt></Where>", 
    "<FieldRef Name=""ID"" /><FieldRef Name=""Title"" />", 
    "4"
    )>      

<cfset ServiceResponse = GetSOAPResponse(siteDataService)>
<cfdump var="#ServiceResponse#">
```

But all I get is that error message:

> Web service operation GetListItems with parameters {{9BE74555-1150-4AC8-ADE7-EE52923D7CE8},3,,4} cannot be found.

Normaly you have to pass xmlNodes the the function, like it is told [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx).

I also tried that, but don't know exactly how to make a xmlNode.
My code, that also doesn't work is this one:

```
<cfset xmlDoc = XmlNew()>
<cfset ndQuery = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "Query")>
<cfset ndViewFields = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "ViewFields")>
<cfset ndQueryOptions = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "QueryOptions")>

<cfset ndQuery = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></BeginsWith></Where>">
<cfset ndViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' />">
<cfset ndQueryOptions = "">

<cfset listsService.GetListItems(
    "{52D3A638-FA12-44E8-9C17-5FBCD2899199}", 
    "", 
    ndQuery, 
    ndViewFields, 
    "1", 
    ndQueryOptions, 
    ""
    )>

<cfset ServiceResponse = GetSOAPResponse(listsService)>
<cfdump var="#ServiceResponse#">
```

Is the way I am calling the webservice the right way?

Thank you,
Kevin

---

EDIT: Thank you for your answer, I think the XML elements work.

```
<cfset listsService.GetListItems(
    "{9BE74555-1150-4AC8-ADE7-EE52923D7CE8}", 
    "{1DD69D36-FD18-42B8-B57D-CCA49FD12AFE}", 
    ndQuery.xmlRoot, 
    ndViewFields.xmlRoot, 
    "1", 
    ndQueryOptions.xmlRoot,
    ""
)>
```

But now i get an "Illegal argument exception" (that's great, because it tells me, that the webservice is responding ;) ):

```
Cannot perform web service invocation GetListItems.

The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:

'' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@f70df9

The error occurred in D:\wwwroot\SharePoint-Tests\blog.cfm: line 83
81 :         "1", 
82 :         ndQueryOptions.xmlRoot,
83 :        ""
84 : )>
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is my new code (April 28)

```
    <cfset xmlDoc = XmlNew()>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "xmlRoot")>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.Query = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "Query")>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.ViewFields = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "ViewFields")>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.QueryOptions = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "QueryOptions")>    


<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.Query.XmlChildren[1] = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "Where")>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.Query.where.XmlChildren[1] = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "GT")>
<cfset xmlDoc.xmlRoot.Query.where.gt.XmlChildren[1] = xmlElemNew(xmlDoc, "Value")>

<cfdump var="#xmlDoc#">

<cfset ndQuery = XmlParse("<Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>0</Value></Gt></Where></Query>", true)>
<cfset ndViewFields = XmlParse("<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>", True)>
<cfset ndQueryOptions = XmlParse("<queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/""><QueryOptions/></queryOptions>", True)>

<cfdump var="#ndQuery#">
<cfdump var="#ndViewFields#">
<cfdump var="#ndQueryOptions#">

<cfoutput>#XMLFormat(ndQuery)#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#XMLFormat(ndViewFields)#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#XMLFormat(ndQueryOptions)#</cfoutput><br>
<cfinvoke 
  webservice     = "#listsService#" 
  method         = "GetListItems"
  returnvariable = "result"
  timeout        = "10"
>
  <cfinvokeargument name="listName"     value="{9BE74555-1150-4AC8-ADE7-EE52923D7CE8}">
  <cfinvokeargument name="viewName"     value="">
  <cfinvokeargument name="query"        value="#ndQuery.XmlRoot#">
  <cfinvokeargument name="viewFields"   value="#ndViewFields.XmlRoot#">
  <cfinvokeargument name="rowLimit"     value="1">
  <cfinvokeargument name="queryOptions" value="#ndQueryOptions.XmlRoot#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="webID"        value="" omit="yes">

  <!--- setting "omit" to "yes" will turn the parameter to null --->
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#result#" label="result">
```

The error message is:

```
Cannot perform web service invocation GetListItems.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Comment: I've moved the info from the answer you posted to your question - in the future, please put clarifications or updates into your question straightaway (you can always edit your own stuff). The "answers" section is for actual answers, I think it's best you delete your post there. :)

Comment: ok Thank you (oder soll ich einfach sagen "Danke dir"? :) )

Do you have some idea, what could cause the IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: You can of course switch to German if you dare. :-D I suppose there is still a misfit in the arguments, which ColdFusion tries to implicitly cast to the type the WS expects, but fails. See the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you get the following example to work:

```
<cfinvoke webservice="http://sharepointserver:16999/blog/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx?wsdl" method="GetUserCollectionFromWeb" password="[pw]" username="[username]" returnvariable="listOfUsers"/>

<cfdump var="#listOfUsers#">
```

Also, is the SharePoint Authentication mechanism to Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!--- parse a bunch of XML documents, case-sensitively --->
<cfset ndQuery = XmlParse("<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></BeginsWith></Where>", True)>
<cfset ndViewFields = XmlParse("<FieldRef Name='ID' />", True)>
<cfset ndQueryOptions = XmlParse("<QueryOptions />", True)>

<cfset listsService.GetListItems(
        "{52D3A638-FA12-44E8-9C17-5FBCD2899199}", 
        "", 
        ndQuery.XmlRoot, 
        ndViewFields.XmlRoot, 
        "1", 
        ndQueryOptions.XmlRoot, 

)>

<cfset ServiceResponse = GetSOAPResponse(listsService)>
<cfdump var="#ServiceResponse#">
```

Maybe it is unnecessary to explicitly pass in the XML root node, and the Web Service handles complete XML document objects just as well. In this case, the following call could also be fine:

```
<cfset listsService.GetListItems(
        "{52D3A638-FA12-44E8-9C17-5FBCD2899199}", 
        "",
        ndQuery, 
        ndViewFields, 
        "1", 
        ndQueryOptions, 
        ""
)>
```

---

EDIT: The MSDN page on [Lists.GetListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) states:

> *`queryOptions`*:
>   To pass an empty value for this
>   parameter, include an empty
>   QueryOptions element as follows.
>
> ```
> <queryOptions 
>  xmlns:SOAPSDK9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
>    <QueryOptions/>
> </queryOptions>
> ```

So, let's try this:

```
<cfset ndQueryOptions = XmlParse("<queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><QueryOptions/></queryOptions>", True)>
```

---

EDIT #2

There may also be a completely different problem - the last parameter of the `GetListItems()` method is optional and should be set to `null` if you don't want to pass a GUID string.

Unfortunately the calling syntax you use is incapable of expressing omitted parameters, and CFML has no literal null. You must convert your call to the more verbose (but more flexible) `<cfinvoke>`/`<cfinvokeargument>` style for this:

```
<cfobject 
  webservice = "http://sharepointserver:16999/blog/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl"
  name       = "listsService"
  password   = "pw"
  username   = "user"
>

<cfinvoke 
  webservice     = "#listsService#" 
  method         = "GetListItems"
  returnvariable = "result"
  timeout        = "10"
>
  <cfinvokeargument name="listName"     value="{52D3A638-FA12-44E8-9C17-5FBCD2899199}">
  <cfinvokeargument name="viewName"     value="">
  <cfinvokeargument name="query"        value="#ndQuery.XmlRoot#">
  <cfinvokeargument name="viewFields"   value="#ndViewFields.XmlRoot#">
  <cfinvokeargument name="rowLimit"     value="1">
  <cfinvokeargument name="queryOptions" value="#ndQueryOptions.XmlRoot#">
  <cfinvokeargument name="webID"        value="" omit="yes">
  <!--- setting "omit" to "yes" will turn the parameter to null --->
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#result#" label="result">
```

More in-depth reading in this regard is on talkingtree.com:
[How to invoke a Web Service while omitting optional service method arguments](http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/7/12/cfinvokeargument-omit-attr)

Comment: That code helped me a lot. But now i have an other problem. (Illegal argument exception)

Comment: Have you tried without the ".XmlRoot"? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Now i'm back from my holidays.
I've tried your code from "Edit #2" but it also throws an exception.
You could see it in my "Edit 2:"

Answer (score 1):

here is another simple demo..

http://dotnetdreamer.com/2009/06/04/moss-web-services-accessing-sharepoint-list-data/